# Proof for homogeneity of elasticities

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, elasticity

Throughout microeconomic literature i see the following restiriction placed on the nature of elasticities in demand system estimation.

This being for some arbitarary good $x$ we require price elasticities and income elasticities to be:

$$\varepsilon(x,p_x)+\varepsilon(x,p_y)+\varepsilon(x,I)=0$$

What is the proof for this? (I cant seem to find it).

Comment: Did you mean the [Engel aggregation](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/18839/42)?

Comment: Whoops wrote the condtion wrong. Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the Marshallian demand function $x^*(p_x,p_y,I)$ is homogeneous degree zero in $(p_x,p_y,I)$ (see [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/12308/42) for a proof). According to Euler's theorem for homogeneous function, it follows that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial p_x}p_x+\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial p_y}p_y+\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial I}I=0\cdot x(p_x,p_y,I)=0
\end{equation}
Dividing both sides by $x^*$, you have 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial p_x}\frac{p_x}{x^*}+\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial p_y}\frac{p_y}{x^*}+\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial I}\frac{I}{x^*}&=0\\
\epsilon_{xx}+\epsilon_{xy}+\epsilon_{xI}&=0
\end{align}